# How to show a column when count other column in result table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table as below:

[image]

Here is my query to get data from MyTable:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct Column1) AS CountCol1 
FROM MyTable  
WHERE ((CONVERT(CHAR, Column2, 104) = '27.09.2019') 
       OR (CONVERT(CHAR, Column2, 104) = '28.09.2019'))
```

In the result table, I want to show not only the count of Column1, but also the value of Column2.

When I try to change the query into this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) AS CountCol1, Column2 AS Col2  
FROM MyTable  
WHERE ((CONVERT(CHAR, Column2, 104) = '27.09.2019') 
       OR (CONVERT(CHAR, Column2, 104) = '28.09.2019'))
```

I get an error message:

> Column 'MyTable.Column2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help me to resolve this issue and show Column2 in my result table.

Comment: seems your date filter is not working, ` (CONVERT(CHAR, Column2, 104)` will yield to `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to get the count of distinct Column1 for each unique value of Column2, this will do the trick:

```
SELECT Column2, COUNT(distinct Column1) AS CountCol1
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Column2
HAVING (....)
WHERE (....)
```

Comment: Does your query sure to get correct count of Column1 when you group Column2?

Comment: I mean when you group Column2, it will effect the count of Column1. For example if we do a physical check and see Column1 get 4 times appeared, but in result table it only get 2. If this is because we group Column2 and gave a false result.

Comment: This query will get the count of distinct Column1 for every unique value of Column2, try it out.

Comment: Aggregate functions without a GROUP BY clause will always return the aggregate for the entire table which means it will return only one row, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, but not that I want.

Comment: You can't get the count of column1 for 2 combined values of column2 AND show the value of column2.  How do you know which value of column2 to show?

Comment: Then mentioned the output you expect with an example.

Comment: I have done a check on your query. It is the correct one. I have mask your question as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues here.

> 1. this query should be followed by `group by`
> 2. `convert(char, col, 104)` will give `yyyy-dd-MM`, you need to format your date parameters.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct Column1) AS CountCol1
    , Column2 As Col2  
FROM MyTable  
WHERE dateadd(dd, 0, dateadd(dd, 0, Column2))
   in (convert(datetime, '27.09.2019', 104), convert(datetime, '28.09.2019', 104))
GROUP BY Column2
```